# How to root Acer Iconia A100?

Tags: rooting, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am having trouble trying to root my Acer Iconia A100 with Android 4.0.3. I have tried several rooting methods and they always fail.

I have the USB debugging enabled, and all the adblock or antivirus apps are off.

I've tried all of these:

- [SRSRoot](http://www.srsroot.com/)
- [KingoRoot](http://www.kingoapp.com/)
- [KingRoot](http://androidxda.com/download-kingroot-application)
- [Z4root](http://z4root.en.uptodown.com/android)
- [How to Root Acer Iconia A100 Tablet](http://theunlockr.com/2012/04/29/how-to-root-acer-iconia-a100-tablet/)

Am I just missing a step somewhere?

Here is the report from the SRSroot app:

```
---= SRS One-Click-Root v5.1 =---

11:29:11 AM - Starting ADB Server..
11:29:16 AM - Manufacturer: Acer
11:29:16 AM - Model: A100
11:29:16 AM - Android Version: 4.0.3
11:29:16 AM - Build ID: Acer_AV041_A100_1.049.00_PA_CUS1
11:29:16 AM - Board ID: vangogh
11:29:16 AM - Chipset Platform: tegra
11:29:16 AM - Getting OffSets.. : 0xd9f0 0xaf47 (True) 
11:29:17 AM - Query Server for Best Method.. Found Rootkit: 4

    ----= Start Rooting Process.. Please Wait =----

11:29:17 AM [+] Testing exploit: root8 (please wait..)
11:29:39 AM [+] Executing root8 exploit Failed. 

11:29:39 AM Auto Root Failed on this device. :( 

11:29:39 AM Rebooting Device and try again...
```

On the Kingo, when I run the Windows application to root the Android it always says that rooting was successful, but when I try to do anything that requires root (like installing busybox) on the Android, it always fails.  Then when I restart the android the rooting is gone.

So, I can root it with Kingo, and if I use SRSRoot after that, it says the android is, indeed rooted, but it doesn't persist.  When I reboot the Android then run the SRSrootkit then it sees that the Android is not rooted (even though it seemed to be before reboot) and it cannot root it itself.

Using the *unlockr* method, I find that the batch file reports `mkdir failed for /data/local/tools, permission denied` with subsequent permissions errors.  And so that method is not able to get root either.

Comment: Maybe I need a driver of some sort?

Comment: I have the adb driver installed on my windows computer, I can see it in device manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I found a viable solution: [Full root for A10x and A5xx ICS. Simple method.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1531646)

They have a link to a tablet driver for the Acer Iconia A100.  I think that is what I needed all along.  I installed that on my PC and ran the script and it worked just fine.

I rebooted the Android and ran the Root Checker application and it reports that the Android is, indeed, rooted.

The solution was simple and it persisted after a reboot!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with 4.0.3 and 4.1, but I fixed it with king root (note the lack of an 'o' after 'king'). It is one of those one click root methods, but it has served me well, and always resides in my toolkit.

Download link (XDA Developers) : http://forum.xda-developers.com/devdb/project/dl/?id=14576&task=get

Comment: When I install the package (xposed installer), it says, "The latest version of Xposed is currently not active. Did you install the framework and reboot?"  Do I have to install something else?  If I use that installer to "install/update framework" it says, "failed to get root access".

Comment: I rebooted the device and tried the Xposed Installer again and it says the same thing.  I belive I have tried this before and I got stuck here the last time, too.

Comment: I am trying this one now: http://androidxda.com/download-kingroot-application  - it is called KingRoot, as you mentioned.  Okay, it says it failed.

Comment: So I tried rooting with Kingo, which seems to provide a temporary root, and then to use the xposed installer to install the framework with root access.  But the xposed installer says, "There seems to be a known issue ("Segmentation fault") with your ROM.  Installing xposed might not work..."

Comment: @BGM Im not sure then.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you might have CWM or TWRP preinstalled. If it is so then you have to find **superSu apk** file which is **flashable**. Some time before I was having same problem for 4.0.3. So just flash it in recovery mode and you will be enjoying the hidden power of android.

Comment: How can I tell if I have CWM or TWRP installed?  I have the superSU apk file - how do I flash it?

Comment: Boot into recovery mode.

Comment: So I just boot into recovery mode and run the package installer for supersu?

Comment: All I can do is boot into the stock recovery mode with the dead robot.

Comment: "*I suppose that you might have CWM or TWRP preinstalled.*" -- and what caused you to assume this?

Comment: Its a pre-requirement in rooting process. It also helps in many ways. So, before rooting you must need to know about this.